# How does cover? work in this case with characters?

Tags: ruby, range

I'm having some troubles trying to understand how `cover?` method for Range class works.

From the docs it is said:

**cover?(val) → true or false** : Returns true if obj is between beg and end, i.e beg <= obj <= end (or end exclusive when exclude_end? is true).

When I do this:

```
test = "A".."X"
```

I expect `test.cover? "AX"` to fail because the object `AX` to me it seems to be outside that range limits. However it returns **true**.  Then I do: `test.cover? "XX"` and it returns **false**

I don't see how AX is in that range and in general I believe it is being difficult to see how **cover?** works for objects that are not Numeric.  So my question is: How is that the object "AX" is in that range, but the object "XX" is not.

Comment: Someone once filed a bug report saying the behavior was confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a shot in the dark here, but I'm assuming it is because "AX" comes *after* "A" so it within the range, while "XX" comes *after* "X" which would be outside the range.

Checking in IRB you can see:

```
"AX" > "A" && "AX" < "B" => true
"XX" > "X" => true
```

Comment: I was confused about the size of strings which seems not to have that importance in cover? method. Thanks!

Comment: The `"AX" < "B"` line is a bit misleading there since `cover?` won't use "B" internally in its comparison.

Comment: @GavinMiller: Correct, #cover? will use >= && <= on A/X; the "B" section was just to help demonstrate that "AX" falls between "A" and "B"